# How to sort mongoose results using indexOf on a field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of items with the field `name`. I find the required items using RegEx, but I can't sort them.

I want the items to be sorted by the number at which the string I'm looking for appears in the field `name`. In other words, I want to sort by `name.indexOf(value)`. For example, I find the items that contain the string `ro` in them, and get items with the following names:

```
Throw
Rope
Prop
Chrome
Rock
```

I want the items to get sorted by the number at which the string `ro` appears in them. So from the list above, I would get this:

```
Rope
^^
Rock
^^
Prop
 ^^
Throw
  ^^
Chrome
  ^^
```

Currently, I sort the results once they've been fetched, like so:

```
d = d.sort(function(a, b) {
  if(a.name.indexOf(val) > b.name.indexOf(val)) {
    return 1
  } else if(a.name.indexOf(val) < b.name.indexOf(val)) {
    return -1
  } else {
    return 0
  }
});
```

Is there a way to sort them using mongoose's `.sort` or `$sort`?

Comment: I'm clueless, can you please update your post along with sample documents from MongoDB? Also post sample output you want to see.

Comment: Edited with an example. I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Got it. I'm not sure if you can do this aggregation framework or using simple query directly but you have option of map-reduce. It will be slow as compared to native queries but will indeed do what are trying to do.

Comment: If that's the case, then I'll keep using what I'm currently using.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense too. I can only suggest do profiling and which ever works better go for it.